# Spring context from within a jar file

Tags: java, spring

I'm developing a desktop application in java using spring and hibernate. I want to package it as a executable jar but I'm having problems loading the context configuration XML from within the jar file.

I package the application as a runnable jar file and when I run the jar file it tells me that the file doesn't exist. I know that from within a jar file I should load an InputStream but there's no ApplicationContext implementation that supports it.

I believe that I'll have to code my own InputStreamXmlApplicationContext and I already tried doing it. I did some research and a little coding:

```
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public class InputStreamXmlApplicationContext extends AbstractXmlApplicationContext {

    private Resource[] configResources;

    public InputStreamXmlApplicationContext(InputStream in) {
        InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(in);
        configResources = new InputStreamResource[] {resource};
        setConfigResources(configResources);
        refresh();
    }

    public Resource[] getConfigResources() {
        return configResources;
    }

    public void setConfigResources(Resource[] configResources) {
        this.configResources = configResources;
    }

    protected void initBeanDefinitionReader(XmlBeanDefinitionReader beanDefinitionReader) {
        beanDefinitionReader.setValidationMode(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.VALIDATION_XSD);
    }
}
```

But I can't get it to work. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try with an [**ClassPathXmlApplicationContext**](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html)

It is a standalone XML application context, taking the context definition files from the class path, interpreting plain paths as class path resource names that include the package path (e.g. "mypackage/myresource.txt").

Useful for test harnesses as well as **for application contexts embedded within JARs**.

Here is how you might do it:

Create yourself a Test class with the following content in it:

```
package com.test;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new 
           ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/com/test/appConfig.xml");
    Integer someIntBean = (Integer) context.getBean("testBean");
    System.out.println(someIntBean.intValue()); // prints 100, as you will see later
  }
}
```

Now create the beans application config file named appConfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">
  <bean id="testBean" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <constructor-arg type="int" value="100" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

You create these files in a package called `com.test`, next to each other. Add classpath references to your spring jars or pack them together into your own single jar file wich should look like this:

```
test.jar --- com
          |   |--- test
          |          |--- appConfig.xml
          |          |--- Test.class
          |
          |-- META-INF
          |        |--- MANIFEST.MF
          |
          |-- org
          |     |--- springframework 
          |               |--- ...
          |               |--- ...
          |-- ....
```

In your manifest file you will have this (use with a trailing blank line):

```
Main-Class: com.test.Test
```

And that is it.

When your run your file (double click or `java -jar test.jar`) you should see 100 printed on the screen. Here is what I get from executing it (notice the 100 I was talking about above - on the last row):

```
Feb 23, 2011 11:29:18 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@ca2dce: 
display name [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@ca2dce]; 
startup date [Wed Feb 23 23:29:18 PST 2011]; root of context hierarchy
Feb 23, 2011 11:29:18 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/test/appConfig.xml]
Feb 23, 2011 11:29:20 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@ca2dce]: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@199f91c
Feb 23, 2011 11:29:20 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@199f91c: 
defining beans [testBean]; root of factory hierarchy
100
```

P.S. You don't absolutely have to include the Spring jars content into your own jar. You can have them available on the classpath when you run your app. I placed them like that since you mentioned one jar. Basically this is what you need:

```
test.jar --- com
          |   |--- test
          |          |--- appConfig.xml
          |          |--- Test.class
          |
          |-- META-INF
                   |--- MANIFEST.MF
```

Comment: I tried using the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext, but it doesn't work from within a jar file. That's why I'm thinking about coding my own ApplicationContext...

Comment: @luizbag: I edited my answer to show you how to do it. You don't need to write your own ApplicationContext class.

Comment: What if they are at the top level of a jar on the classpath? E.G. .jar/myconfig.xml?

Answer (score 10):

Provided your jar is in classpath; you can import bean definitions from jars using import

```
<import resource="classpath:/path-to.xml"/>
```

Comment: I can't even load the spring-config.xml that may import that resource!

Answer (score 2):

Why not use ClasspathXmlApplicationContext and load them using the classpath relative path?

Comment: new ClasspathXmlApplicationContext("/path-relative-to-root-package");

Comment: try: "classpath*:/path-to-app-ctx"

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to run your application as `java -jar myapp.jar`

In this case, use class [ClassPathXmlApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html) within your class with the method `main`.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    String config[] = { "spring-beans.xml" };
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(config);
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.getBean("dataSource", DataSource.class);
}
```

It's a terrible idea to try to implement your own ApplicationContext. That's too much work and too much room for errors.